# Is there English equivalent of phrase "If two friends fight the third outsider will take away with the prize shield"

Tags: idiom-requests, phrase-requests, proverb-requests

Is there English equivalent of marathi phrase

> Dhoghanchya bhandnya madhe (Fight between both) tisryacha fayda (will
>   yield third's (outsider's) profit).

If two friends fight the third outsider will take away with the prize shield. So the wisdom says you should not fight with each other over something in front of third party otherwise the third party will feign as arbitrator and flee away with the bounty. I suppose there is a fairy tale which i don't recollect probably about a crow if i am not wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I had to think immediately of

> While two dogs are fighting for a bone, a third runs away with it.

[Oxford reference](http://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/acref/9780199539536.001.0001/acref-9780199539536-e-2343) has a reference to Chaucer for this.

[wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/two_dogs_fight_for_a_bone,_but_a_third_runs_away_with_it) also has an entry.

It doesn't seems to be a very common expression in English, although in my mother tongue it is very well known. See also this [BBC](http://www.bbc.co.uk/languages/yoursay/phrasebook_classics/polish/where_two_are_fighting_the_third_wins.shtml) thread for some more international examples.